# Is there any difference between Future<Terminated> returned by ActorSystem.terminate() vs ActorSystem.whenTerminated()?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I have my java application uses Akka framework for message routing. During application startup I create Actor System and then creates number of top level actors. Now while shutting down my application, I call  Await.result(actorSystem.terminate(), Duration.Inf()) and want my shutdown thread wait till actor system terminates. I came across other API ActorSystem.whenTerminated() which too return Future and does similar stuff.. Just want to know the difference between these two API's? should I use ActorSystem.whenTerminated() instead ?

Comment: From reading the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html) it seems like `whenTerminated()` waits for termination that may happen while `terminate()` triggers termination and returns the future to wait for the result - Javadoc on `terminate()` states: "Terminates this actor system ...". So I'd say unless you want to start termination right away use `whenTerminated()`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply. So did you mean Future returned by terminate() and Future returned by whenTerminated() would differ ?

Comment: I'd guess the futures are providing the same data and complete at the same time, for me it looks the difference is whether termination is triggered right away or not.

Answer (score 0):

The future returned by `ActorSystem.terminate()` is in fact `ActorSystem.whenTerminated()`, as can be seen [in the source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/77d757c4ec74ecb231256f5b76f7bdd2fc797b7a/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L1058).  The only difference is that `whenTerminated` gives you a future which tells you when the termination has completed, while `terminate` actually starts the process of termination.

So in a process which is trying to stop the actor system, there's not really a difference between:

```java
scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.toJava(actorSystem.terminate())
    .thenAccept(t -> System.out.println(t))
    .join();
```

and

```java
actorSystem.terminate();
actorSystem.getWhenTerminated()
    .thenAccept(t -> System.out.println(t))
    .join();
```

However,

```java
actorSystem.getWhenTerminated()
    .thenAccept(t -> System.out.println(t))
    .join();
```

could be anywhere else in the system (e.g. in your `main`) relative to the `terminate` call.